# Enable data and sms on CDMA network programmed number Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: sms, mobile-data, sim-card, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

My Galaxy S7 edge (G935P) sim card slot is broken. It doesn't recognize any sim card I put.
I managed to program my phone number into the phone using CDMA Network. I can make calls, but I can't send sms texts or enable data.
When I try to enable data I get a message "Insert sim card to access network service".
The same thing when I try to send a text "sending failed".
Is there any way to trick the phone to think there's a sim card when there isn't.

Comment: No... Why not just get a new SIM card?

Comment: (acejavelin) Read the question carefully before writing useless comments. The sim card is fine, it's the sim card slot that is broken.

Comment: lol... My mistake, I read to fast apparently and apologize. But my answer is still the same, no, in modern phones the SIM is required. Note you can get a replacement SIM tray for a very small investment, it is available on Amazon, eBay, and I imagine other similar sites depending on your location. https://www.amazon.com/Card-Holder-Slot-Samsung-Galaxy/dp/B01GDMDCYO